# MSDN Subscription for the lone developer

Tags: msdn

I'm looking to get an MSDN Subscription and I see a number of sites offering [2 year subscriptions](http://www.software-intl.com/storeproduct548.aspx) versions. Are these sites offering a regular version that I can buy or are they for Software Assurance customers only? I don't want to buy one and find out I cannot activate it because I'm not associated with a company that has SA.

Comment: You're probably going to want to call either the company that's selling it or Microsoft Developer Support to ensure that you get the correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked with Microsoft and these subscriptions are genuine.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out Microsoft's Empower program for ISVs. I'm not sure if you qualify (I believe you need to be incorporated and developing a commercial product or service), but the cost savings may be worth the hoop jumping. Note that it appears to be ending in May of 2010 (transitioning to another program).

https://partner.microsoft.com/global/40011351